# get wrong account on my website

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I have a written a game which uses a rented appache server. I friend showed me that as he was logged in suddenly his user changed and he was logged in with a different user. How can this happen? And how can I prevent it from happening? I guess he was logged in for a longer time doing nothing an as he refreshed he was suddenly in another account.

I guess this has something to do with session keys, but I didn't find answers. Maybe because my knowledge about sessions is very limited.

Every script starts with `session_start();` and except the login script every script checks if the following function returns true.

```
function isLoggedIn(){
    if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $loggedIn = TRUE;
    }
    else {
         $loggedIn = FALSE;
    }
    if ($loggedIn == FALSE) {
        header("Location: login.php?displayinfo=1");
        die("<br /><br /> you must be logged in.");
    }
    return $loggedIn;
}
```

**edit:**
after that I do
`$user = getUserById($_SESSION["user_id"])`.

Someone else reported that it happend just after it entered his password.

If someone can deliver a best practice source for staying logged in on a php website I would be thankful too.

Comment: this code only checks if session has a user_id but has nothing to do with your problem.  `I guess he was logged in for a longer time doing nothing` - I also suspect this as the cause of the problem. Check the actual login script.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: This can go wrong in so many ways. Check if you set  the id in the session somewhere else.

Comment: I only set the Session variable after the user entered the right

Comment: If you get another user than must be something like "if the user is is not set, set the user like this: ............" Maybe it gets messed up by other script that sets the same variable. Maybe user_id is used buy the game itself and its some kind of internal game account ID. Try prefixing that session variable with something like main_acc_user_id.

Comment: I checked my scripts and after I do `$user = getUserById($_SESSION["user_id"])` there is no further access to `$_SESSION["user_id"]`. I also change the key for the session variable. Hopefully this fixes it. But i have my doubts.

Comment: @Solmyr I changed the key name to something very unique. However, I got reported that it happend again. I am really frustrated because most of the times it works fine and last year nobody reported anything. Is it possible that my new server provider is responsible?

Comment: Maybe its some kind of "keep me logged" functionality that is broken. Try to find out where and how it happens and when it happens check the id of the new user, try to find some logic. Maybe the new user is some page id or the newest member so the broken part of system just take it from db.
Maybe you can implement some kind of logging mechanism, to log in file or DB what are the user doing. Like record ip, user_id, current url and refer url. Once there is 2 records of same ip with different user_id check the urls maybe you can find the problem. After fix remove it so you don`t waste resource.